# Separar Letras de uma string e adicionar em um ComboBox

Tags: delphi

Procurando na web achei essa função para retorna as letras dos HDDs.

```
function tbDriveLetters: string;
{ Uso: S := tbDriveLetters; - retorna 'ACD' se existir as unidades A:, C: e D: }
var
  Drives: LongWord;
  I: byte;
begin
  Result := '';
  Drives := GetLogicalDrives;

  if Drives <> 0 then
    for I := 65 to 90 do
      if ((Drives shl (31 - (I - 65))) shr 31) = 1 then
        Result := Result + Char(I);
end;
```

Preciso de outra função para separar as letras e adicionar no ComboBox para que cada Letra seja um item do Combobox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de fazer o processo através de uma função, você pode popular o `ComboBox` diretamente.

```
procedure tbDriveLetters;
{Uso: S := tbDriveLetters; - retorna 'ACD' se existir as unidades A:, C: e D:}
var
  Drives: LongWord;
  I: byte;
begin
  Drives := GetLogicalDrives;

  if Drives <> 0 then
    for I := 65 to 90 do
      if ((Drives shl (31 - (I - 65))) shr 31) = 1 then
        ComboBox.Itens.Add(Char(I));
end;
```

Mas, se precisa realmente que seja feito por função, imaginando que seja em Units diferentes, você pode modificar o Retorno da sua função que é String para um TComboBox.

Ou seja, você pode retornar um TComboBox já populado para o componente que o cliente vai usar na tela.

Construção:

```
function tbDriveLetters:TComboBox;
```

Alimentação:

```
Result.Itens.Add(Char(I));
```

Atribuição:

```
SeuComboBox := tbDriveLetters;
```

Comment: Fiz o teste e fico bom...